# Is item-based collaborative filtering feasible with Neo4J/Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, mahout, gremlin

I'm testing Neo4J as a potentially more efficient alternative to (non-distributed) Mahout for **item-based** collaborative filtering (i.e. 'recommend items for User based on his and others' preferences), and have seen excellent examples using Gremlin, e.g. http://markorodriguez.com/2011/09/22/a-graph-based-movie-recommender-engine/ - but none for Cypher.

Is this practical/feasible with Cypher, or should I just bite the bullet and start using Gremlin (and the REST API)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried my open source project? It's name is [reco4j](http://www.reco4j.org), it is a graph based recommender engine based on neo4j as graph database.

It is in an early stage but it works for your use case.

Cheers,
Alessandro

Comment: That looks like the best of both worlds, so I'll definitely give it a try - thanks.

Comment: I did have quite a bit of trouble getting something working, as the documentation is out-of-date and I had to search the Git commits. Main problems so far: lock problems with an Embedded Database already running, and the Recommender insists Nodes have a "type" property, but I currently use a Label for this kind of thing. Should I add both?

Comment: Is the project still alive?

Answer (score 4):

We've done these kinds of recommendations using Neo4j and Cypher in particular, are are really pleased with the results. 
Of course it could span into a couple of Cypher queries depending on the complexity of logic you have but it's entirely do-able.
I realize this is a extremely simplified approach but it might help you compare a gremlin/cypher kind of approach:

Gremlin: http://blog.everymansoftware.com/2012/02/similarity-based-recommendation-engines.html

Cypher: http://thought-bytes.blogspot.in/2012/02/similarity-based-recommendations-with.html

Disclaimer: I am the author of the Thought Bytes post